# Is it possible to track a call backwards beyond the last PBX?

Tags: asterisk

We receive international calls into an Asterisk server (13.20) where some of the calls are automated, meaning there is no person involved, sort of M2M.

It is important for us to know where those automated call are coming from. Since it is easy to generate a call with faked ID we want to strengthen the authentication by identifying the original network from where the call was made.

When looking at the Asterisk logs I can see that a call came from Twilio for example, but that's it, no more tracking information.

My question:

Is it possible to track a call backwards beyond the last PBX who transferred the call to my server?

Comment: How are these calls coming in ? PSTN/SIP/AIX etc.

Comment: I am mostly interested to track SIP calls as they have the highest probability to carry faked CLI.

Comment: Here in the UK I see *many* calls on and to the PSTN with fake CLID daily.

Comment: it is impossible to track fake CLI but maybe , there is hint on SIP headers. so you can mirror sip port and then by  Homer/wireshark , you can save sip packets. and then you can follow IP/CLI. thats all you can.

Answer (score -1):

Some operators send some tracking in sip headers

For see more info, check sip debug.

```
asterisk -r
sip set debug on
```

However most of operators not provide for clients info about path of calls, some even not store it for internal use.

Comment: "sip set debug on" is how I get the information about the last leg, as explained above this is not enough.

Comment: Sorry, no way get info provider not want you see.